# Display information from a list vertically

Tags: 2010, list, infopath

We are using Sharepoint 2010. There is an old hospital census that I need to give our users on our Sharepoint site before I can kill the old web server. On the web server, it is using an ODBC connection. On Sharepoint I want to keep it simple for them. Basically the people who update the census could easily be trained to do this in a list. My question is how to display it vertically? With the regular list web part it is horizontal which won't work well on smaller monitors. I had thought about using Infopath to display the information, but it won't let me set up the filter on a text box. I am still learning Infopath so I could be doing something wrong. Any ideas on how best to display the information from the list vertically?

Comment: can you show an image of how you looking to show it ?

Comment: I ended up deciding to display an infopath form instead that pulls from a list. That seems to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to go the simpler path. I created an Infopath form that loads from a list and the users change the information they need to change in the list. Its been working great so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SharePoint `Mobile View`. Go to the desired library and in the library tab click `Library Settings` and click on a view of your choice. On the bottom of the page you can customize the mobile view and get its URL.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. By the time I had seen this I had already switched gears.